# Regular expression for extracting domain from an input

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract the *`domain.com`* from an input that can be in the following formats and structure:
**1.** `x.x.domain.com`
**2.** `x.domain.com`

Once I am getting user's email, for example:
user@x.x.domain.com
I am able to remove the first part of the email address:
**`user@`** 
by the following regex:
**`/^.+@/`**

I want to be able by using the regex over the 2 formats to get the `domain.com` right away and not manipulate the input several times until getting the domain.
I thought maybe to count the number of dots from the input and then to do some logic, but it looks so complex for this small solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What about `[^.]+\.[^.]+$`?

Comment: @KooiInc the user is trying to extract the domain and tld without the subdomains.

Comment: @ctwheels - looks good only for the 2 options, but once I am getting a valid email address, I can't use it.

Comment: why can't you use it?

Comment: Because I am not able to catch using the regex the domain part of regular email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `RegExp`: split the e-mail address twice, slice from the last split and join the result. Plus two `RegExp` ideas. Take your pick.

```js
const getDomain = address => 
  address.split("@")[1].split(".").slice(-2).join(".");

const getDomainRE = address => 
  address.match(/\.\w+/g).slice(-2).join("").slice(1);
  
const getDomainRE2 = address => 
  address.match(/(?:(@|\.)\w+){2}$/)[0].slice(1);

console.log(getDomain("user@x.x.domain.com"));
console.log(getDomain("user@x.domain.com"));
console.log(getDomain("user@abc.x.y.z.domain.com"));
console.log(getDomainRE("user@x.x.domain.com"));
console.log(getDomainRE("user@x.domain.com"));
console.log(getDomainRE("user@abc.x.y.z.domain.com"));
console.log(getDomainRE2("user@x.x.domain.com"));
console.log(getDomainRE2("user@x.domain.com"));
console.log(getDomainRE2("user@abc.x.y.z.domain.com"));
```

Comment: I've used your solution at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is regular expression for domain name

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"
```

should also manage x.x.domain.co.uk

original pattern uses

```
"(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]"
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Regex way:

```js
let str1 = "x.domain.com";

let str2 = "x.sdfsdf.google.com";

let str3 = "www.subdomain.yahoo.com";

let reg = /[^.]+\.[^.]+$/gi;

console.log(str1.match(reg)); // domain.com

console.log(str2.match(reg)); // google.com

console.log(str3.match(reg)); //yahoo.com
```

Simple javascript:

```js
function getDomain(str){
  
  let arr = str.split(".");
  
  if(arr.length < 2){
    console.log("Invalid domain name");
    return null;
  }
  else{
    return `${arr[arr.length-2]}.${arr[arr.length-1]}`;
  }
}

let str1 = "x.domain.com";

let str2 = "x.sdfsdf.google.com";

let str3 = "www.subdomain.yahoo.com";

console.log(getDomain(str1)); // domain.com

console.log(getDomain(str2)); // google.com

console.log(getDomain(str3)); //yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't specifically ask for it, but you may want to consider [country codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) a top level domains as well (e.g. `.au`, `.uk`).

If required, you could achieve it with the following:

```js
function getDomainFromEmail(domain) {
  const domainExpression = /((\w+)?(\.\w+)(\.(ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bl|bm|bn|bo|bq|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cw|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|er|es|et|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mf|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|za|zm|zw))?)$/i;
  const match = domainExpression.exec(domain);
  
  return match ? match[1] : null;
}

console.log(getDomainFromEmail('email@example.com'));
console.log(getDomainFromEmail('email@sub.example.com'));
console.log(getDomainFromEmail('email@sub.sub.example.com'));
console.log(getDomainFromEmail('email@example.com.au'));
console.log(getDomainFromEmail('email@example.co.uk'));
console.log(getDomainFromEmail('email@sub.example.co.uk'));
console.log(getDomainFromEmail('email@sub.sub.example.co.uk'));
console.log(getDomainFromEmail('email@bit.ly'));
console.log(getDomainFromEmail('email@domain.other'));
console.log(getDomainFromEmail('email@nomatch'));
```

The long expression `(ad|ae|...|zm|zw)` is a list of country codes combined into a regular expression.

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
(@).*
```

The first group of the output is @ and the second group is domain.com